# Different routes same component in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I use the same component for different routes but when I navigate between routes of the same component the URL is getting changed but page content is the same.

I used this solution:

```
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
  route.url.subscribe(val => {
     //Code Here
  });
}
```

I now have the expected behavior but another problem: Angular does not save the previous URL in the browser history.

If the flow is: A -> B -> C where B and C are the same component, if I click on the back button in the browser, I navigate to A instead of B.

Comment: What are the URL paths for B and C.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Angular doesn't maintain the state by default. However, you can make it do it by the following:

```
ngOnInit(){
    window.history.pushState( {} , 'ComponentName', '/path' );
}
```

You can write a service which will push the new state everytime you navigate to some component. Once you maintain the state, then pressing the back button will take you to that component.

I've not tested this but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this in a somewhat angular way is to create two new components and have the only html in each just the selector for the desired component. Then in the router just define the component as one of the two new components and Angular will register them as different components and fix the issue. Ive ran into this problem before and this was the easiest most straightforward solution I found.